# How do I set the appendix counter in a new book document?

Tags: numbering, counters, appendices, multiple-files

I have a multi-volume work, and the several appendices are distributed across each volume. For example, Appendices A through D are at the end of Volume 1 as they relate to the subject matter therein, E through H at the end of Volume 2 for the same reason, etc.

I have opted to create each volume as its own LaTex file. How would I go about setting the appendix counter on the subsequent documents (Vol. 2+) to maintain this alphabetical labelling and but not have multiple Appendix As, Bs, etc.?

I am using the latest version of TexStudio.

Comment: Maybe `\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{4}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the counter for chapters to the number of appendices up to that point in every volume.

Volume One:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \blinddocument
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Appendix a}
    \chapter{Appendix b}
    \chapter{Appendix c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Volume Two:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \blinddocument
    
    \appendix
    \setcounter{chapter}{3}
    
    \chapter{Appendix d}
    \chapter{Appendix e}
    \chapter{Appendix f}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\setcounter{chapter}{6}` for volume Three, and so on